# Version numbers of Rails plugins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, version

Is there a standardized command to determine the version number of a plugin, similar to `ruby script/about`? For example, I need to figure out which version of `exception_notification` I'm running. Here's my list of plugins in my `vendor/plugins` directory

```
active_merchant         annotate_models         calendar_date_select    gruff                   mysql_bigint            routing_navigator       ziya
acts_as_audited         attachment_fu           exception_notification  in_place_editing        redbox                  spawn
acts_as_list            authorization           gemsonrails             make_resourceful        restful_authentication  uml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `exception_notification` plugin has any version number, except for the commit label, which can be seen here:

http://github.com/rails/exception_notification

However, most of the newer plugins have a VERSION file which you could read in. Or, if you're using a gem, you can find out its version by doing a simple `gem list`, but this should already be in your `Gemfile` or `config/environment.rb`